# SSL, Nginx, X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch error

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have Nginx server with the SSL. I'm trying to submit a SSL certificate. After I restart Nginx I'm getting the error:

```
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(".../example.com.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

I found this [**solution**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains).  But, I'm not using of any bundles.

Any ideas on what is the issue here?

Comment: exactly the same situation as http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains but I'dont have any chain files...

Comment: What files do you have?  Is this a new cert?  Can you clarify what you've done so far?

Answer (score 3):

cat star_domain_name.crt ca.pem  > star_domain_name.pem

ca.pem  -> root cert of your ssl provider

---

```
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/star_domain_name.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/star_domain_name.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Comment: Note, the order matters here: you have to create the PEM using the domain's crt first, followed by the intermediate CA PEM.